# functional equation, how to solve

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, generating-functions

Suppose $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $F,G: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.
$$F(x, y) = \frac{x\circ Ay}{x^TAy}$$
$$G(x, y) = \frac{x\circ By}{x^TBy}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are some matrices, $\circ$ is component-wise product ([Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product)).
My question is how to build (find) functions $F^{1/2}$ and $G^{1/2}$ such that given $x_2=F(x_0, y_0)$, and $y_2 = G(y_0, x_0)$:
$$x_1 = F^{1/2}(x_0, y_0), y_1=G^{1/2}(y_0, x_0)$$
$$x_2 = F^{1/2}(x_1, y_1), y_2 = G^{1/2}(y_1, x_1)$$

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can first think the case n=1

Comment: I cannot edit your question but there's a typo
[Hadamar]-->[Hadamard]
after the name of the mathematician Jacques Hadamard.

Comment: if n=1 then F and G maps everything nonzero to one

Comment: This was also asked at the same time on math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331802/functional-equation-how-to-solve.

Comment: It seems to me that bo.gu's "answer" is a sensible suggestion.  (It would have been better posted as a comment, but it looks like bo.gu may not have enough reputation points to do so.)  Looking at $n=1$ cuts through the clutter and boils the OP's question down to the following:  "Suppose $x_i$ and $y_i$ are real numbers.  Are there functions $f$ and $g$ such that given $x_2=1$ and $y_2=1$, we have $x_1=f(x_0,y_0)$, $y_1=g(y_0,x_0)$, $x_2=f(x_1,y_1)$, and $y_2=g(y_1,x_1)$."  It's not clear (to me, at least) what this means.